# Is the following sequence equidistributed mod$1$ : $x_n=\{10^n\cdot a\}_{n\in\mathbb N}, a\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q ?$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, uniform-distribution, ergodic-theory

> Is the following sequence [equidistributed mod$1$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion) $\big($ or equidistributed  in $[0,1]\big)$ :
> $$x_n=\{10^n\cdot a\}_{n\in\mathbb N}, a\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q.$$

I'm familiar with the [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion), but i'm not sure if it works here...

Answer (score 1):

No. For example let $a=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}\in\mathbb R \setminus \overline{\mathbb Q}$ be the Liouville's constant, then $x_n<0.2$ for any $n$.

Comment: But for $n=5$ and $a = \sqrt{2} , x_5 = 0.3562373... >0.2 $

Comment: The sequence of $x_n$ might be equidistributed for some values of $a$, but @just-a-user has given a particular example for which it is not equidistributed. If your question hasn't been answered (by “no, not for every such $a$, at least”), try to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes you are right,  i thought that it stands for every irrational $a$ , thank you for the great answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

@just-a-user gave a great short answer, but in case someone doesn’t see why the given $a$ works, here’s a longer (but basically equivalent) answer.

If $\ a\!\!\!\mod\!\!1\ $ has decimal expansion $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4\!\dots$, the sequence $x_n$ is $$x_1=0.d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4\!\dots\\ x_2=0.d_2 d_3 d_4d_5\!\dots\\ x_3=0.d_3 d_4d_5d_6\!\dots\\ x_4=0.d_4d_5d_6d_7\!\dots\\ \dots .$$

If the digits $d_i$ are all, say, $0$ and $1$, then these $x_n$ are all less than $0.2$.

So let $a$ be your favorite irrational number with only $0$s and $1$s in its decimal expansion, and the sequence of $x_n\!\!\!\mod\!\!1$ will be far from equidistributed. Liouville’s constant $a=0.110001000000000000000001000\dots$ is one choice for $a$, but there are many others!

Comment: Quite beautiful answer to be honest, thank you.